# Issue with substitute sed on bash

Tags: javascript, bash, sed

I'm having an issue.. My server got hacked by a malicious script.. It added the following code on all the website on my server.

```
<script type='text/javascript' src='http://siu.edu.bd/includes/framework.js'></script>
```

First I want to delete this from all my php files on my server.
I want to use the following sed command but some how I got a return error which says :

```
"Syntax error near unexpected token '<'"
```

Here is the code I tryed

```
find /home -type f | xargs sed -i 's$<script type=\'text/javascript\' src=\'http://siu.edu.bd/includes/framework.js\'></script>$ $g'
```

I don't understand why it does not work..

Thanks in advance ,

Anselme

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Wrong quoting issue in sed, use:

```
sed "s~<script type='text/javascript' src='http://siu.edu.bd/includes/framework.js'></script>~ ~g"
```

Problem in your command is that in shell you can escape single quote using `\'` that's why its better to use double quotes in sed with a different regex delimiter `~` as shown above.